# VBA to list all object names of a powerpoint presentation

Tags: vba, powerpoint

I'm looking for a way to automatically make a list of all object names in a PowerPoint presentation through a simple VBA script. I name certain objects using the selection pane on several slides and need to generate a list of all objects' names on each slide. My knowledge is unfortunately close to nil but I managed to adapt a script I found on here

```
Sub ListAllShapes()

Dim curSlide As Slide
Dim curShape As Shape

For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
    Debug.Print curSlide.SlideNumber
    For Each curShape In curSlide.Shapes


                Debug.Print curShape.Name


    Next curShape
Next curSlide
End Sub
```

The problem with the script is that it reaches the limit of the debug screen buffer of 190 or so lines and cuts the first portion of the shapes list. If it is possible to write the debug output to an external txt file that would be great.

Another solution which would bypass the debug line limit is to put a filter of the shape name so it only prints names with a certain prefix. e.g. all shapes that have a name starting with "ph-"

Other solutions are welcome as well. Thanks.

Comment: Instead of using Debug.Print, append each bit of text to a string variable (e.g. sList = curShape.Name & VBCRLF) then have a look here for a way to write the string out to a text file: General-purpose routine for writing a string to a text file
http://www.pptfaq.com/FAQ00514_General-purpose_routine_for_writing_a_string_to_a_text_file.htm

Comment: thanks a lot @SteveRindsberg I'm afraid I am having a hard time deciphering this method as I have no experience with VBA :(

Comment: another solution which would bypass the debug line limit is to put a filter of the shape name so it only prints names with a certain prefix e.g. all shapes that have a name starting with "ph-"

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Using your code and as @SteveRindsberg suggests - output to a text file.
This code will create the file in the same folder as your presentation:

```
Sub ListAllShapes()

    Dim curSlide As Slide
    Dim curShape As Shape
    Dim lFile As Long
    Dim sPath As String

    sPath = ActivePresentation.Path

    lFile = FreeFile

    Open sPath & "\Object Names.txt" For Append As #lFile

    For Each curSlide In ActivePresentation.Slides
        Print #lFile, curSlide.SlideNumber
        For Each curShape In curSlide.Shapes
            If Left(curShape.Name, 3) = "ph-" Then
                Print #lFile, curShape.Name
            End If
        Next curShape
    Next curSlide

    Close #lFile

End Sub
```

Comment: Thanks, works as a charm! Now if I can only figure out a way to integrate a name prefix filter :)

Comment: I've updated the code so it will only print out those objects starting with "ph-".  It will still print out each slide number even if there aren't any "ph-" objects on that slide.

Comment: You are a true star! Thank you very much @darren. This is exactly what i was after. Hopefully it would be helpful for others out there as well

Comment: @DarrenBartrup-Cook Ditto Bogomil's thanks; appreciate your stepping in and filling in the gaps for him.

Answer (score 0):

I once wrote some code, aiming to do just that - try it out, hope that helps!

```
Sub ReadPPT()
Dim WB As Workbook
Dim PP As PowerPoint.Application
Dim Pres As PowerPoint.Presentation
Dim SLD As PowerPoint.Slide
Dim SHP As PowerPoint.Shape
Dim PresPath As String
Dim r As Long
Dim sh As Long

Set WB = ThisWorkbook
With ThisWorkbook.Sheets(1)

'Let user select a ppt-file and select its path
PresPath = Application.GetOpenFilename("PowerPoint Presentations (*.pptx), *.pptx", _
            , "Open Presentation", "Open", 0)

If PresPath = "" Then Exit Sub

'Create ppt-Application and show it
Set PP = CreateObject("PowerPoint.Application")
PP.Visible = True

'Open previously selected ppt-file
Set Pres = PP.Presentations.Open(PresPath)

sh = 1
For Each SLD In Pres.Slides
    r = 2
    If SLD.Shapes.Count > 9 Then
'        .Cells(0 + r, 2) = SLD.SlideID
'        r = r + 1
        For Each SHP In SLD.Shapes
            If SHP.HasTextFrame Then
                If SHP.TextFrame.HasText Then
                    .Cells(0 + r, 2) = CStr(SHP.Name)
                    .Cells(0 + r, 3) = CStr(SHP.TextFrame.TextRange.Text)
                    r = r + 1
                End If
            End If
        Next SHP
    sh = sh + 1
    End If
Next SLD

PP.Quit

End With
End Sub
```

Comment: Wow thanks for the quick reply. I'm looking for something way simpler though. Please check my edited question. Thanks